# Strongly Typed Configuration and custom key mappings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Let's say I have following settings,

```
"SomeInfo": {
    "Some:Key": "value",
}
```

and following class,

```
public class SomeInfo
{
   public string SomeKey {get;set;}
}
```

and following configuration,

```
services.Configure<SomeInfo>(Configuration.GetSection("SomeInfo"));
```

I just wanna tell ASP.NET Core that map `Some:Key` with a custom property name `SomeInfo`. I cannot change the settings json but can change the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just going to have to manually map the values:

```
services.Configure<SomeInfo>(o =>
{
    var section = Configuration.GetSection("SomeInfo");
    o.SomeKey = section["Some:Key"];
    // etc.
});
```